# How did they get $\frac{x+y}{x^2y^2} |x-y|$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

How did they get $\frac{x+y}{x^2y^2} |x-y|$? Shouldn't it be $\frac{x+y}{x^2y^2} |y-x|$?

[image]

Comment: $|z|=|-z|$ ....

Comment: wow yeah duh, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$|x-y|=|-(y-x)|=|y-x|$$